# Is there a Way to localize an Application on Various Platforms

Tags: localization, development-environment

We are developing an Application which runs on various plattforms (Windows, Windows RT, MacOSX, iOS, Android).

The Problem is how to manage the different localizations on the different Platforms in an Easy Way. The Language Files on the different platforms have various formats (some are xml based, others are simple key-value pairs and others are totally crazy formats like on MacOS)

I'm sure, we aren't the first company with this problem, but I wasn't able to find an easy to use solution o achive the possibility to have one "datasource" where the strings are collected in different languages (the best would be an User Interface for the translators) and then can export it to the different formats for the different platforms.

Does anybody has a solution for this problem?

Greetings
Alexander

Comment: I think, that you can create your own format and your own localization mechanizm, that wrapping over all platforms. Not easy, but available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [GNU Gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) toolchain for management and at runtime use either

- some alternate implementation for runtime reading like [Boost.Locale](http://www.boost.org/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html),
- own implementation (the .mo format is pretty trivial) or
- use [Translate Toolkit](http://toolkit.translatehouse.org/) to convert the message catalogs to some other format of your liking.

You can't use the `libintl` component of [GNU Gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), because it is licensed under LGPL and terms of both Apple AppStore and Windows Live Store are incompatible with that license. But it is really trivial to reimplement the bit you need at runtime.

The [Translate Toolkit](http://toolkit.translatehouse.org/) actually reimplements all or most of [GNU Gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) and supports many additional localization formats, but the Gettext `.po` format has most free tools for it (e.g. [poedit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poedit/) for local editing and [Weblate](http://weblate.org/) for online editing) so I recommend sticking with it anyway. And read the [GNU Gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) manual, it describes the intended process and rationale behind it well.

I have quite good experience with the toolchain. The [Translate Toolkit](http://toolkit.translatehouse.org/) is easy to script when you need some special processing like extracting translatable strings from your custom resource files and [Weblate](http://weblate.org/) is easy to use for your translators, especially when you rely on business partners and testers in various countries for most translations like we do.

[Translate Toolkit](http://toolkit.translatehouse.org/) also supports extracting translatable strings from HTML, so the same process can be used for translating your web site.

Answer (score 1):

I did a project for iPhone and Android which had many translations and I think I have exactly the solution you're looking for.

The way I solved it was to put all translation texts in an Excel spreadsheet and use a VBA macro to generate the .string and .xml translation files from there. You can download my example Excel sheet plus VBA macro here:

http://members.home.nl/bas.de.reuver/files/multilanguage.zip

Just recently I've also added preliminary Visual Studio .resx output, although that's untested.

edit:
btw also my javascript [xcode/eclipse converter](http://members.home.nl/bas.de.reuver/files/stringsconvert.html) might be of use..

Comment: I've played with the converter a bit, but it completely neglects important corner cases like strings containing newlines, quotes, backspaces and such. Yes, I've see quite a few such strings in the wild.

Comment: Okay I can maybe guess what strings with newlines or quotes should look like, but backspaces..? I'll look into this if you could send me some of these corner cases, so an .xml or .strings file with some of these exception strings, my mail address can be found here http://members.home.nl/bas.de.reuver/

Answer (score 1):

you can store your translations on https://l10n.ws and get it via they API

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am the CTO and Co-Founder at Tethras, but will try to answer this in a way that is not just "Use our service".

As loldop points out above, you really need to normalize your content across all platforms if you want to have a one-stop solution for managing your localized content. This can be a lot of work, and would require much coding and scripting and calling of various tools from the different SDKs to arrive at a common format that would service the localization needs of all the various file formats you need to support. The length and complexity of my previous sentence is inversely proportional to the amount of work you would need to do to arrive at a favorable solution for all of this.

At [Tethras](http://www.tethras.com), we have built a platform that alleviates the need for multi-platform software publishers to have to do this. We support all of the native formats from the platforms you list above, and can leverage translations from one file format to another. For example, translate the content in Localizable.strings from your iOS app into a number of languages, then upload your equivalent strings.xml file from Android or foo.resx from Windows RT to the system, and it will leverage translations for you automatically. Any untranslated strings will be flagged and you can order updates for these strings.

In effect, Tethras is a CMS for localized content across many different native files formats.

Comment: Tethras looks really cool, but is there a possibillity to share strings between projects? If not, it won't fix our problem...

Comment: Yes, by all means you can share translations across projects. All localizable content ends up getting extracted from the native file formats that you upload to your account. The system identifies matching strings across project and across files, and leverages existing translations automatically for you. For example, if we translate X strings in Localizable.strings for your iOS app, and you upload Y strings in strings .xml for your Android app, the system will identify all matching strings in English between both files. iOS translations will be leveraged automatically into strings.xml.